# How to merge two strings alphabetically?

Tags: java, arrays, compareto

Beginner here.
I am trying to merge to strings in alphabetical order using the `compareTo` method, but my `fullfirstarray[i] = arrayone[i];` and `fullsecondarray[i] = arraytwo[i];` lines as well as my final black of code are giving me errors, mostly OutofBoundsExceptions

```
`import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math; 


class NamesMerge
{
public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); 

  int flag = 0;
  int i = 0;
  String name = "";
  String input = "";
  int firstcounter = 0;
  int secondcounter = 0;

  String[] fullfirstarray = new String[firstcounter];
  String[] fullsecondarray = new String[secondcounter];

  System.out.println("Enter the values for the first array, up to 10000 values, enter 'End' to quit");

  //first array prompt (arrayone)
  String[] arrayone = new String[10000];

    input = scan.nextLine();

    input = input.toLowerCase();
    input = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);

  while (!(input.equals("End")))
  {
    System.out.println(input);
    arrayone[i] = input;
        i++;
    input = scan.nextLine();
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    input = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);
  }

  if (input.equals("End"))
  {
    System.out.println("Enter the values for the second array, up to 10000 values, enter 'End' to quit");
  }

  //next array prompt (arraytwo)
  String[] arraytwo = new String[10000];

    input = scan.nextLine();
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    input = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);

  while (!(input.equals("End")))
  {
    System.out.println(input);

    arraytwo[i] = input;
        i++;
    input = scan.nextLine();
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    input = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);    
  }

  //PRINTING THE FIRST ARRAY
  if (input.equals("End"))
  {
    System.out.println("First Array");
  }


  for (i =0; i < arrayone.length; i++)
  {
    if  (arrayone[i]!=null)
    {
      System.out.print(arrayone[i] + " ");
             firstcounter++;  
      fullfirstarray[i] = arrayone[i];
    }
  }

  //PRINTING THE SECOND ARRAY
  System.out.println("\nSecond Array");

  for (i =0; i < arraytwo.length; i++)
  {
    if  (arraytwo[i]!=null)
    {
      System.out.print(arraytwo[i] + " ");
              secondcounter++; 
      fullsecondarray[i] = arraytwo[i];
    }
  }


  //counter for total names
  System.out.println(firstcounter);
  System.out.println(secondcounter);


  //merge
  String[] merge = new String[firstcounter + secondcounter];

  int arrayoneindex = 0; 
  int arraytwoindex = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < (firstcounter + secondcounter); i++)
    if (fullfirstarray[i].compareTo(fullsecondarray[i])<0)
    {
    merge[i] = fullfirstarray[i]; 
    arrayoneindex++;
    }
  else
    if (fullsecondarray[i].compareTo(fullfirstarray[i])<0)
    {
      merge[i] = fullsecondarray[i];
      arraytwoindex++;
    }
  for (i = 0; i<merge.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.print(merge[i]);
    }
    }

    }
```

Comment: That's a lot of repeated code. Did your course get to the part where you declare methods yet?

Comment: No, the course is not asking for methods in this assignment.

Comment: Could you please create methods? It is terrible to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code of yours. Please compare the both and see the differences. Here are the high level of changes I did

1. Refactored the code
2. Handled edge cases
3. Sorted the input arrays

If you have any additional questions let me know.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class NamesMerge {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the values for the first array, up to 10000 values, enter 'End' to quit");
    String[] arrayOne = getArray(scan);
    System.out.println("Enter the values for the second array, up to 10000 values, enter 'End' to quit");
    String[] arrayTwo = getArray(scan);

    sortArray(arrayOne);
    sortArray(arrayTwo);
    //merge
    String[] merge = mergeAndSort(arrayOne, arrayTwo);

  }

  private static String[] mergeAndSort(String[] arrayOne, String[] arrayTwo) {
    String[] merge = new String[arrayOne.length + arrayTwo.length];

    int arrayOneindex = 0;
    int arrayTwoindex = 0;
    int mergeIndex = 0;

    while (arrayOneindex + arrayOneindex < arrayOne.length + arrayTwo.length
        && arrayOneindex < arrayOne.length
        && arrayTwoindex < arrayTwo.length) {

      if (arrayOne[arrayOneindex].compareTo(arrayTwo[arrayTwoindex]) < 0) {
        merge[mergeIndex] = arrayOne[arrayOneindex];
        arrayOneindex++;
        mergeIndex++;
      } else if (arrayOne[arrayOneindex].compareTo(arrayTwo[arrayTwoindex]) >= 0) {
        merge[mergeIndex] = arrayTwo[arrayTwoindex];
        arrayTwoindex++;
        mergeIndex++;
      }
    }

    while (arrayOneindex < arrayOne.length) {
      merge[mergeIndex] = arrayOne[arrayOneindex];
      mergeIndex++;
      arrayOneindex++;
    }
    while (arrayTwoindex < arrayTwo.length) {
      merge[mergeIndex] = arrayTwo[arrayTwoindex];
      mergeIndex++;
      arrayTwoindex++;
    }
    System.out.println("\nMerged sorted array");
    print(merge);
    return merge;
  }

  private static String[] getArray(Scanner scan) {
    String input;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    input = scan.nextLine();
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    input = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);

    while (!(input.equals("End"))) {
      System.out.println(input);
      list.add(input);
      input = scan.nextLine();
      input = input.toLowerCase();
      input = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);
    }
    return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
  }

  private static void print(String[] arr) {
    if (arr != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
      }
    }
  }

  private static String[] sortArray(String[] arr) {
    String temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[i].compareTo(arr[j]) < 0) {
          temp = arr[i];
          arr[i] = arr[j];
          arr[j] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println("SortedArray");
    print(arr);
    return arr;
  }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using `List<String> list` to add the inputs?

Comment: I don’t wanted to create a string array of size 1000 just for nothing. ArrayList is built on top of array it effectively manages internal array size based on number of elements you add to it. Hope this helps. But if u have a hard requirement to not use List it should be fairly simple.

Comment: In the getArray method, how would I add the input values to the array  before knowing the length of the array, which is the number of inputs? I do not know the number of inputs yet so I can't declare the array, but I still need a command that adds the inputs to the array that would be created. (this is using array, not list)

Answer (score 0):

Your code [smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)

As i can see what you trying to do you need to full two arrays with strings and after this combine them in new array with alphabetic order.
Try this:

```
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.addAll(Arrays.asList(arrayOne));
    result.addAll(Arrays.asList(arrayTwo));
    result.sort(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    String[] resultArray = result.toArray(new String[]{});
```

Arrays version of this code:

```
    String[] result = new String[one.length + two.length];
    System.arraycopy(one, 0, result, 0, one.length );
    System.arraycopy(two, 0, result, one.length, two.length);
    Arrays.sort(result, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this section of the course does not include lists. Thank you for your help, though.

Comment: @18bwhite i added version with arrays

Answer (score 0):

THe problem with the exceptions is given when you try to access to your array 'fullfirstarray'. 
When an array is declared and instantiated you are telling the compiler how many elements is it going to have, and you are telling to the compiler it will have 0:

```
int firstcounter = 0;
int secondcounter = 0;

String[] fullfirstarray = new String[firstcounter];
String[] fullsecondarray = new String[secondcounter];
```

So when you try to fullfill the arrays this way:

```
     fullsecondarray[i] = arraytwo[i];
```

you try to access an element of the array that does not exists.

Try to create the arrays when you know the length you need to them.

Code will fail on the next lines, but I encourage you to try to figure out the problem ;)

Comment: Even when I add the amount required in the int firstcounter and secondcounter before I create the array, I still get an OutofBoundsException, this time with the length of the longest array. Why is there this error even when the counter amount matches the amount I input into the array?

Answer (score 0):

These lines are causing your OutOfBoundsException (they're creating arrays of length 0):

```
    int firstcounter = 0;
    int secondcounter = 0;
```

change those and exceptions disappear